# A short novel about a couple traveling to a utopian/dystopian community somewhere in Asia

Tags: story-identification, novel, dystopia

I remember the protagonist is a man who travels a long distance with his sick wife from Europe by train to live in a utopian community where there's no money and people are doing whatever they like. The protagonist's wife is having some lung problems and it is stated that the dry climate in Asia will be good for her.

In later parts of the novel the protagonist and his wife are having some problems in understanding the mechanics of the society as people randomly come in and start taking their furniture and household items. There's no concept of money and people seem to take what they need. No one seems to work on a daily basis. They just work when they feel like it. The protagonist might be an artist, writer or painter. The city is a little chaotic and some streets have incomplete statues and works of art thrown around randomly.

Towards the end things start to get worse but I can't remember the details.